# How to extract an XML element attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have narrowed in on the URLs that I would like to extract from a webpage using Nokogiri.

Unfortunately, when I try to get the attribute from this object I'm unable to. It's there, I can even see it, but I don't know how to retrieve the URL.

Please take a look at this Nokogiri object. I've tried using `url = titleArea.attr("href")` as well as `url = titleArea.attribute("href")`.

The thing I'm interested in is this:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fdc727d8d98 name="href"
    > value="watek-nowy-pomysl_1515">]
```

From this object:

```
> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdc72796f9c name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fdc727d9bd0 name="class" value="
> subject_new">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fdc727d9bbc name="id"
> value="tid_1515">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdc727d8f64
> name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fdc727d8d98 name="href"
> value="watek-nowy-pomysl_1515">]
> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdc727d808c "nowy pomysÅ�">]>]>
```

The `.to_s` representation is nice and beautiful but I can't extract the href from the string, I need to use Nokogiri's functionality:

```
"<span class=\" subject_new\" id=\"tid_1515\">\n  <a href=\"watek-nowy-pomysl_1515\">nowy pomys&#xC5;&#xFFFD;</a>\n</span>"
```

Comment: please share the code snippet so that I can try running locally

Answer (score 0):

Your object is a `span` element that contains an `a` element. You must select the `a` element first before accessing the attribute.

```
str = "<span class=\" subject_new\" id=\"tid_1515\">\n  <a href=\"watek-nowy-pomysl_1515\">nowy pomys&#xC5;&#xFFFD;</a>\n</span>"
title_area = Nokogiri::XML(str)
title_area.at('a')['href'] # => "watek-nowy-pomysl_1515"
```

Comment: Without the string representation. How can I do it from the ugly nokogiri object? I just did a to_s to show how the structure looks. It's already parsed as a nokogiri object. How can I understand that and get data from that?

Comment: `title_area` is a nokogiri object, best install `pry` and play with it on the command line.

Comment: You don't get it from "the ugly Nokogiri object", you use Nokogiri's methods for the object to get it, just as you would any other object. The final line above is exactly how you'd do it. This is covered many times here on SO, and on the internet, including Nokogiri's tutorials.